# Single Sign On to Communities

Tags: community, single-sign-on

I have an org that is hosting a community. Now we have the internal and external users i.e. Users with `Community Partner` licenses and users with just force.com licenses. I need to find a way to ensure that the external users can also log into the community.

Single Sign On will only work if the

```
org that is the Identity Provider and the org hosting the community are different orgs.
```

That is not the scenario here. Both are in the same org.

So are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: for community we get different SSO url. so try with that.

Comment: Yes, the URL is different but the org is the same and it's not allowing me to do that

Comment: try in incognito window.

Comment: It didn't work.
I'm sorry but how would it? Be it incognito or the regular window, the org is still the same right?

Comment: I think external users already have community license available. Also did you add their profile in APP?